# How to use Map<String,Long> for datastax

Tags: hashmap, cassandra, cql, datastax

I am using datastax and want to retrieve Map from Cassandra

Cassandra has map with String,bigint , bigint maps to long in Java but I cannot have Map with primitive types. So how to use Map ?

Below is my table creation script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dealsstorea.deals1( 
   otla text, 
   dtla text , 
   **types Map < text,bigint >**, 
   travelers bigint, 
   pkgRatePlanCode text, 
   pkgRoomTypeCode text,
   numRooms bigint, 
   PRIMARY KEY ((...),
    ..));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code i used to convert the map data type into string.

--------Code-----------------------

public static String getMaptoSring (DataType dataType, Row row, String columnName) throws ClassNotFoundException
   {

```
  String  mapstr = "";
 if(row.getColumnDefinitions().getType(columnName).getName().name().equalsIgnoreCase("map"))
 {           
     Map<?, ?> map = row.getMap(columnName, Class.forName("java.lang.String"), Class.forName("java.lang.String"));
     Set<?> set = map.keySet();
     Iterator setIterator = set.iterator();
     while(setIterator.hasNext()){
         Object key = setIterator.next();
         String value = map.get(key).toString();
         if(mapstr =="" )
             mapstr="{"+key.toString()+":"+value;
         else
             mapstr = mapstr+","+key.toString()+":"+value;

     }
     mapstr = mapstr+"}"; 

     //System.out.println("Map Key and value are as following: Key :: "+ key.toString() + ", value :: "+ value);

 }
 return mapstr;
```

}

Comment: I might not be clear but basically, in cassandra table, I have a map of <string,int>  and it I am retrieving it as resultRow.getMap("types", String.class, int.class); into a Map<String,Integer>  and it fails with error _"Column types is a map of class java.lang.String->class java.lang.Integer (CQL type map<varchar, int>), cannot be retrieve as a map of class java.lang.String->int"_.   So for now , I had to make the Map in Cassandra as String,String to work around this.  Any better solution of keeping it String,int in cassandra

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are using the Java driver to Select from a CQL table that has a column of type Map and you want to load it into a Java object.

If that is the case use a Java TreeMap

```
Map<String, Long> myMap = new TreeMap<String, Long>();
```

Java types String and Long map to CQL text and bigint respectively.

Comment: I tried for Integer,I got below error. I also tried for long,   and the error in that case was java.lang.Integer and cassandra int do not match. here is the error for int _"Column types is a map of class java.lang.String->class java.lang.Integer (CQL type map<varchar, int>), cannot be retrieve as a map of class java.lang.String->int"_